# Display data on blur

Tags: javascript, blur

I have a simple table (dynamically generated from an array) where i can put the amount of pieces so the price can calculate automaticly (on blur) in the price field. Both fields are form-input fields.
So the source therefore looks like this:

```
<?php 
foreach($ItemArray['1'] as $key => $value) { 
echo '
<tr>
    <td height="30" valign="middle">'.$value['nr'].'</td>
    <td valign="middle">'.$value['product'].'</td>
    <td valign="middle">'.$value['describe'].'</td>

    <td valign="middle" id="stockprice_'.$key.'">
    <input name="Field_Price_'.$key.'" id="Field_Price_'.$key.'" value="'.$value['price'].'" type="text" /></td>

    <td valign="middle" class="box_darker" id="amount_'.$key.'">
    <input name="Field_Amount_'.$key.'" id="Field_Amount_'.$key.'" type="text" /></td>

    <td valign="middle" id="price_'.$key.'">
    <input name="Field_Total_'.$key.'" id="Field_Total_'.$key.'" type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>'; }
;?>
```

The way i would realize that is when a user inputs any amount (in "Field_Amount_") and go out from this (onblur) so the amount field should take the value (from "Field_Amount_") and then have to put the total price (in "Field_Total_"). So i try this solution, but it won't work.

```
$(document).on('blur', '[id^=Field_Amount_]', function(){

    Amount = $(this).parent().find('[id^=Field_Amount_]').val();
    StockPrice = $(this).parent().find('[id^=Field_Price_]').val();
    Price = $(this).parent().find('[id^=Field_Total_]');
    RowPrice = Amount * StockPrice;

    if(Amount) { $(Price).text(accounting.formatNumber(RowPrice, 2, ".", ","));}
});
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion how i have to do this? Many thanks.

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Please define "won't work." What do you expect to happen, what really happens, and how have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector from `[id^=Field_Amount_]` to `input[id^=Field_Amount_]`

Comment: you are right... the input[id^Field_Amount_] is required in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that the code:

`$(this).parent().find('input[id^=Field_Amount_]').val();`

actually points to the `<td>` tag itself.

```
The `$(this)` is actually pointing to the input field of the amount.

var amount = $(this).val();

                 //field - td - tr
var stockPrice = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[id^=Field_Price_]').val();
```

and so forth...

Comment: Probably makes more sense to use `$(this).closest("tr").find(...`

Comment: Thank you. For any reason the "closest" won't work. I found the solutions into post above. :)